# EndTimedEvent for Flurry Analytics on Android

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

My question is regarding the timedEvents in flurry for Android. I have three activities in my android app say A, B  and A is my entry point of my activity. I am starting and ending the flurry session in `onStart()` and `onStop()` respectively for each activity A, B. I have a timed event say ‘event_test’ and I start this event on click of a button present in activity A  and I  navigate to B and spend some time in B. I have another button in B on click of which I am ending the timed event ‘`event_test`’.  Ideally ‘`event_test`’ should capture the entire time I spend in activity A and activity B. But it is only capturing the time I spent in activity A but not in B. I would greatly appreciate if some one can help me in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take `Android Activity lifecycle` into consideration in this case.

As per the activity lifecycle the `onStop()` of the current activity() CAN be called AFTER the `onStart()` of the next activity.

In that case a new session will be started before ending the previous session. It may cause the problem you are facing now. In this scenario , I don't know, how the `Flurry` APIs will respond. Only `Flurry` support team can answer that.

However I can suggest a workaround which may not be the best.
You can create your own timer, which will start when button is clicked in `Activity` A, and will stop at button click in `Activity` B. This way you can get the time duration you are looking for. And you can use that time in `logevent` as parameter.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: According to the flurry a new session will not be created until and unless the gap between endsession and startsesiion is more than 10 secs, so it should continue to act as same session

Comment: that is case when startsession is called after endsession of pre. activity, but I am suggesting a case where startsession of nxt act. is called before endsession of pre. act.